# Feed Me: How to format JSON for a table field?

Tags: json, table-field, plugin-feedme

I need to import some data into a **table** field.

What's the best way to format the data in my original JSON feed?

I've tried this:

```
[
    "first value",
    "second value",
]
```

and this:

```
[
    {"col1": "first value"},
    {"col2": "second value"},
]
```

But neither of those JSON formats seems to be importing the data properly.

**How should I format my data in JSON, so that it may be imported into a table field?**

---

**MORE INFORMATION**

I've read [these docs](https://sgroup.com.au/plugins/feedme/content-mapping/field-types#table), but apparently I'm still doing something wrong.

My current JSON looks like this...

```
"altTitles": [
    {
        "title": "Morke"
    }
]
```

Where `altTitles` is my table field, and `title` is the only column.

I believe I've properly mapped the field...

[image: mapping]

Yet for whatever reason, the table fields are not populating...

[image: empty table]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this a number of ways, and essentially just need an array-like structure to represent the rows.

```
"Table": [
  {
    "one": "Option1",
    "two": "Option2"
  },
  {
    "one": "Option3",
    "two": "Option4"
  }
]
```

This issue might be related to your feed however. In the dropdown, you have `<altTitles> eg:` - there should be a value from your feed in there. According to your example, you should also be mapping to `altTitles/title`.

My example above shows:

[image]

Comment: Looks like I had it mapped to `altTitles`... I didn't even see that `altTitles/title` was there! Thanks crawf, you're a lifesaver!