# Feed Me: How to format CSV data for a table field

Tags: plugin-feedme, table-field, csv

Similar to the other post [Feed Me: How to format JSON for a table field](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/20598/feed-me-how-to-format-json-for-a-table-field). I'm looking for a solution on how to format the CSV field so I can import it as a table field. Basically I have a list of products and each product has multiple serial numbers which I'd like to have each as a row in the table. So for the serial number field I've tried things like:

```
"[12345, 54211, 55511]"
"[{12345}, {54211}, {55511}]"
"[{"12345"}, {"54211"}, {"55511"}]"
```

Any thoughts on the best way to approach this field?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a feed-me.php file under your /config directory, then you can configure the data delimiter:

```
<?php

return [
    '*' => [
        'pluginName' => 'Feed Me',
        'dataDelimiter' => '-|-',
    ]
];
```

On my side, that is not working all the time (if almost never), but the doc says it should!

(https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/feed-me/docs/get-started/configuration)

(https://github.com/verbb/feed-me/issues/449  ---> created just now)

Comment: Sorry it took me a bit to get back to this. Thanks so much for creating that GH issue. This definitely sounds like an issue of support for Super Table or Matrix fields for me as well.